# How to retrieve the value of javascript

Tags: javascript, parameters, comments, disqus

I have been trying to retrieve the comments on CNN. The comments are maintained by disqus where disqus provides an api to retrieve its comments by setting two parameters named disqus_shortname and disqus_identifier. The comments of each news article are obtainable except cnnmoney since disqus_identifier is delivered by javascript. How do i retrieve the value of disqus_identifier from javacript? Thanks a lot.

The code is obained from the javacript of cnnmoney

```
(jQuery);if(typeof CNNM==="undefined"){var CNNM={};}if(typeof cnnmsocial==="undefined"){var cnnmsocial={};}var disqus_shortname="cnnmoney";var disqus_identifier=location.pathname;var disqus_url="http://"+location.host+location.pathname;var disqus_developer=0;var disqus_config=function()
```

The link below shows that identifier is more likely an url but i have no idea how to get it.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13789089/disqus.jpg

Comment: Show us your code. What have you tried?

Comment: i listed some information that i found. I know they are trivial but this is all i can do so far.